# nil pointer evaluating interface {}.name when deploy helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm and kubernetes, so I maybe missed something.
I have created a Helm Chart to deploy MISP. Unfortunately, I am now getting the following error.

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: misp/templates/serviceaccount.yaml:4:11: executing "misp/templates/serviceaccount.yaml" at <include "misp.fullname" .>: error calling include: template: misp/templates/_helpers.tpl:7:40: executing "misp.fullname" at <.Values.misp.name>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.name
```

My helpers.tpl looks like this:

```
{{/*
This is a helper template file that defines the misp.name variable.
*/}}


{{- define "misp.fullname" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name .Values.misp.name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}


{{- define "misp.name" -}}
misp
{{- end -}}

{{- define "misp-chart.name" -}}
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}

{{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name.
We truncate at 63 chars because some Kubernetes name fields are limited to this (by the DNS naming spec).
If release name contains chart name it will be used as a full name.
*/}}
{{- define "misp-chart.fullname" -}}
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride }}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride }}
{{- if contains $name .Release.Name }}
{{- .Release.Name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}

{{/*
Create chart name and version as used by the chart label.
*/}}
{{- define "misp-chart.chart" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Chart.Name .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}

{{/*
Common labels
*/}}
{{- define "misp-chart.labels" -}}
helm.sh/chart: {{ include "misp-chart.chart" . }}
{{ include "misp-chart.selectorLabels" . }}
{{- if .Chart.AppVersion }}
app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion | quote }}
{{- end }}
app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
{{- end }}

{{/*
Selector labels
*/}}
{{- define "misp-chart.selectorLabels" -}}
app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "misp-chart.name" . }}
app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
{{- end }}

{{/*
Create the name of the service account to use
*/}}
{{- define "misp-chart.serviceAccountName" -}}
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create }}
{{- default (include "misp-chart.fullname" .) .Values.serviceAccount.name }}
{{- else }}
{{- default "default" .Values.serviceAccount.name }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and my templates/serviceaccount.yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ include "misp.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "misp.name" . }}
    chart: {{ include "misp.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
```

And here my values.yaml

```
# Default values for misp.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: coolacid/misp
  tag: latest
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8080

ingress:
  enabled: false
  # Used to create an Ingress record.
  hosts:
    - misp.example.com
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  tls:
    # Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
    - secretName: misp-tls
      hosts:
        - misp.example.com

database:
  mariadb:
    enabled: true
    image:
      repository: bitnami/mariadb
      tag: 10.3.23-debian-10-r44
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    rootUser:
      password: password
    # databaseName: misp
    # user: misp
    # password: misp

redis:
  enabled: true
  image:
    repository: bitnami/redis
    tag: 6.0.6-debian-10-r0
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi
```

Thank you for your help

try to regenerate the files

Comment: Your helper refers to a `.Values.misp.name` but your Helm values don't seem to include a `misp` key.  Is that missing, or do you expect something else to provide it?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think this is missing. So I am not really sure how to include this key. Do you have an short example?

Comment: In what you've included already, you'd have a `.Values.service.type`, for example.